# AMPscript create PersonAccount

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript

I try to create a Salesforce Person Account through AMPscript. I create it as an Account and provide the LastName + RecordTypeId but I just get an error. Can anybody provide an code snippet to create a person account from Marketing Cloud?

Comment: could you paste your code here?

Comment: `SET @sfpersonaccount=CreateSalesforceObject("Account", 4 "Salutation", @salutation, "FirstName", @fname, "LastName", @lname, "RecordTypeId", "XXXXXXXX" )`

Comment: Ouch! RecordType wasn't assigned to API User's profile - that was the issue. Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work - I'm locked out of environments for now, but can you test and if it doesn't work, then paste the error message here?

```
%%[ 
var @id, @LastName, @recordtypeid
set @LastName = "Johnson"
set @RecordTypeId = "01258000000gtubAAA" /* Believe you need to use the 18 digit one*/
set @id = CreateSalesforceObject("Account", 2, "LastName", @LastName, "RecordTypeId", @RecordTypeId)
]%%
This is the Salesforce Id: %%=v(@id)=%%
```

Comment: Ouch! RecordType wasn't assigned to API User's profile - that was the issue. Thanks anyway.

PS: 15 digit Id works as well :)

Comment: Ahhhh makes sense ! And Good to know :-D

Comment: Is there a way to retrieve the PersonContactId when creating the Person Account? In your recommended script it will return the accountId

Comment: You Could do a lookup after creation (i.e. RetrieveSalesforceObject and then just retreive the PersonContactId :)

Comment: Ok, thats how I've actually just done it. However, some AMPscript solutions doesn't feel really clean, since I currently query the SF API around 6-8 times just to create one Personaccount, but I guess I'll get used to it :D

Comment: Hehe person accounts are a fun thing :-) but even Classic apex code (SF core) need to do a lookup to get PersonContactId as far as i can see :-D